# query is not returning kwargs results django

Tags: django

The kwargs are getting passed into my query but the values are not showing in my drop down box, no values are being displayed in the drop down box.

forms.py

```
class ChooseCarMakeModelForm(forms.Form):

        car_model = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=CarModel.objects.none())
        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            ids = kwargs.pop('ids', None)
            super(ChooseCarMakeModelForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

            if ids:
             print 'it worked'
                self.fields['car_model'].queryset = CarModel.objects.filter(make=ids)
            else:
                print 'didnt work'
```

view

```
form = ChooseCarMakeModelForm(request.POST,ids=car_model_ids)
```

models

```
class CarMake(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):         
        return self.name

class CarModel(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    price = models.IntegerField()
    make = models.ForeignKey('CarMake')

    def __str__(self):         
        return self.name
```

Comment: What is the `make` field on `CarModel`? Also, in the meantime try `make__in=ids` for your filter.

Comment: ill upload my models its a foreign key

Comment: I assume `ids` is just a list of `ids` from `CarMake`?

Comment: ids is the make of the car, which I am passing through to forms to get the models for that make of car

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with your queryset. Assuming ids a list of `CarMake` objects,(`[<SomeMake>, <SomeOtherMake>]`, and not a list of ids: `[1, 3, 4]`), your filter will return zero results because no `CarModel` has a `make` that is a list of `CarMake`. What you want to do, is filter to all `CarModel`'s that are *in* the list, which [Django makes pretty simple](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#in):

```
self.fields['car_model'].queryset = CarModel.objects.filter(make__in=ids)
```

If, on the other hand, `ids` is in fact a list of `ids` from `CarMake` (ex. `[1, 3, 4]`), you would make just a small change:

```
self.fields['car_model'].queryset = CarModel.objects.filter(make__id__in=ids)
```

Comment: is it somthinig to do with this line of code car_model = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=CarModel.objects.none())

Comment: Shouldn't be an issue - where you have `print 'it worked'`, try `print ids` and see what that spits out.

Comment: it gets the id that i am passing to my query

Comment: Can you expand your `views.py`  to show where `car_model_ids` is defined?

Comment: I have just tried to replace my ids variable with the number 1 I get the error int object is not irritable

Comment: It needs to be a list, aka `ids = [1, 2, 3]`